# set Content-Type to json but request comes in as x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: node.js, ajax, post

I am using ajax to send post to my app. In postman everything works as expected, however in browser, data comes in as `x-www-form-urlencoded` and data is missing.

Below is my ajax and postman configurations and their corresponding headers in req...

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': "application/json"
        }, // send as JSON
        data: JSON.stringify(formData),
        method: 'POST'

    });


 headers:
      { host: 'localhost:8080',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0',
        accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        referer: 'http://localhost:8080/',
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content-length': '0',
        connection: 'keep-alive',
        'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
        pragma: 'no-cache',
        'cache-control': 'no-cache' }
```

[image]

```
 headers:
      { data: '{"name":"tester", "email": "t@t.com", "message":"This is a test"}',
        contenttype: 'application/json',
        datatype: 'xml/html/script/json',
        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
        'postman-token': 'cbaa5cbe-0ab8-4328-abfd-f5dc6a6acd90',
        'user-agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.1.1',
        accept: '*/*',
        host: 'localhost:8080',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        'content-length': '0',
        connection: 'keep-alive' }
```

also my relevant server code:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
//handle urlencoded data
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log(res);
    console.log('----------------------------------------------------------');
    console.log(req);
    //var jsonData = JSON.parse(req.headers.data);
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.data);
    let transporter = courier.createTransport({...});
    let mailOptions = {...};
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
        if (error)
            console.log(error);
        else
            console.log('email sent:' + info.response);
    });
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'Projects',
        projects: projects
    });
});


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'Projects',
        projects: projects
    });
});
```

plz halp!

Comment: Have you tried `dataType:'json'`?

Comment: Sending the data in `header`? Really? Please check your postman you have done that and I dont know how you are getting expected answer with this

Comment: @AnikethSaha  you're right, i sent them in the header.However, when I send the data in the body I can't see the data anywhere in req. I am using the `body-parser` package but body receives `{}`

Comment: @Rodrigo can you show the route and the node.js server code for the request and also can you tell me the route link which is rending this view where you are doing this ajax call ?

Comment: @AnikethSaha I have updated my question. The post receives the ajax request and the get is the one responsible for rendering

Comment: I think there is an error in route . You are sending a post request through the ajax call which is returing a view so in the ajax response a it wont work if you want you just return the html code in the post reuqest for the `/` route then add `datatype:"html"` in you ajax call and return the html from the server

Comment: Every ajax call expects to manage the response coming from server by the ajax call itself . You can simply send a ajax call and tell thw server to manage the response and restrict the ajax to work with response . So in post request in server you return html code instead of rendering and take that code in ajax success response and work with that

Comment: Actually I think the error was with how I was submitting the form. I had a javascript function listen to form.submit(), but I think the input button with type submit fired off first. @AnikethSaha

Comment: You can still get the input values in the submit method so can you show the whole method of submitting

Answer (score 0):

on you can just simply:
`JSON.parse(data)`
inside your 
`success: function(data){`
`var object =JSON.parse(data);`
`}`
once the json parses the data you can do what ever you like.